# Specify directory when using cp command

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way of copying certain files out of a certain directory when I am not currently in that directory?

For example, I am writing a shell script that copies files:

```
cp \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/composer.json \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/composer.lock \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/composer.phar \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/gulpfile.js \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/index.php \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/package-lock.json \
/var/www/api
```

But I feel this looks quite unreadable, I want to do something more like:

```
cp \
/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/composer.json \
composer.lock \
composer.phar \
gulpfile.js \
package-lock.json \
/var/www/api
```

The "/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13" is never going to change.

Anything neater than the first example?

Comment: Use a symbolic link or a variable containing the directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use shell brace expansion:

  ```
  cp /some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13/{composer.{json,lock,phar},gulpfile.js,index.php,package-lock.json} /var/www/api
  ```
- You can use shell variables:

  ```
  src=/some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13

  cp $src/composer.{json,lock,phar} $src/gulpfile.js $src/index.php /var/www/api
  ```
- You can use bash arrays:

  ```
  paths=(
      $src/composer.{json,lock}
      $src/gulpfile.js
      $src/index.php
  )

  cp "${paths[@]}" /var/www/api
  ```
- You can combine all of the above.
- You can use a completely different deploy process that doesn't involve cherry-picking a bunch of individual files every time, e.g. `git checkout`.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1501698/bash-brace-expansion-and-cp

Answer (score 1):

```
(
  cd /some/long123/random/directory/somewhere13
  cp composer.json composer.lock composer.phar gulpfile.js index.php package-lock.json /var/www/api
)
```