# Bash Brace Expansion and cp

Tags: bash

I have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

src=/a/really/long/dirctory/sd65asdasd/
dest=/var/www/api

# Remove everything
# Could maybe copy it as a backup (?)
sudo rm -rf $dest

# Start building new file structure
sudo mkdir $dest
sudo chown user:user $dest
cp -R $src/bin /$src/config $src/plugins $src/src $src/webroot $dest

cp $src/composer.{json,lock,phar} $src/gulpfile.js $src/index.php $dest
```

But I am getting:

`cp: cannot stat '/a/really/long/dirctory/sd65asdasd/composer.{json,lock,phar}': No such file or directory`

If I do a simple copy directly in the commandline without the bracket expansion it works without problem.

Any ideas?

```
echo $BASH_VERSION  = 4.4.19(1)-release
```

Comment: Tip: Put your variables in double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually running the script under Bash; you're running it under `/bin/sh`.

/bin/sh is only required to provide the baseline "POSIX shell" features, so while on one system it *may* be Bash, on others it may not be. For example, Debian almost always uses the *dash* shell as /bin/sh.

The goal of dash is to be fast and minimal; brace expansion is not a standard feature, so Dash doesn't provide it (like it doesn't provide many other syntax features, like arrays).

Similarly, on other distributions the shell might be busybox-ash, or Korn shell (which actually does support {} expansion), or even zsh.

To actually use Bash, change the script's header to `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Very insightful. I didn't realise I should of specified the type of shell #!/bin/bash

Comment: Have you described somewhere the difference between the `#!/bin/bash` She-Bang and the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` She-Bang, @grawity?

Comment: In short, bash is not always in /bin (especially on BSDs it is not). Sven Maschek's https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#env is a good page for anything shebang-related.

Comment: Thanks for that, @grawity. We are currently attempting to learn the _Bourne-Again_ Shell-Scripting Environment. Reading the output generated by the `man bash` Operating System Command has proved to be quite a challenge so far.